# fscanf only scans in the first value of my file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct account{
int accountId;
char *name;
double amount;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
struct account *Ptr;
int i,j;
int size=0;

fscanf(file,"%d",&size);
if(size==0)
{
    printf("Unable to open file");
    return 0;
}
printf("%d",size);
Ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct account)*size);

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    fscanf(file,"%d%s%lf\n",&(Ptr+i)->accountId,(Ptr+i)->name,&(Ptr+i)->amount);
}

for(j=0;j<size;j++)
{
    printf("%d%s%lf\n",((Ptr+j)->accountId),(Ptr+j)->name,((Ptr+j)->amount));
}

fclose(file);
free(Ptr);

return 0;
```

}

This is used to read in the input file
2
2 Harry 23.45
8 Sally 100.91

Somehow the code reads in the first 2 for size and the second 2 during the for loop but nothing else

Comment: you need spaces in your scanf format string

Comment: I have already tried that, I thought C does not matter about spacing or anything like that.

Comment: @pm100 OP does **not** need spaces in the `scanf()` format string.  All `scanf()` specifiers, except `"%c"`. `"%n"`. `"%["` consume leading white-space.  Adding a space may look better, but does not change this code's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, because you are reading data into an uninitialized pointer:

```
fscanf(file,"%d%s%lf\n",&(Ptr+i)->accountId,(Ptr+i)->name,&(Ptr+i)->amount);
//                                                   ^^^^
// This pointer is uninitialized ----------------------+
```

There are three ways to address this:

- Make `name` an array, rather than a pointer, e.g. `char name[MAX_NAME]`, or
- Use `malloc` to allocate space to `name` before reading data into it.
- Read into a temporary buffer, then `malloc` the exact number of chars.

Comment: so I would need to malloc that in the main function?

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson That's one approach. Using an array would be another valid approach.

Comment: it has to be in pointer format so for instance I would have to change the code to

Comment: name=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is required by the standard to be `1` in all implementations, so it's just `malloc(10)` for a nine-character name (one more is for null terminator).